# How to apply ConvertColor function to RGB values listed in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, rgb, xyz

I'm running an experiment where I need to compare the consistency of RGB values selected from two different time points. To do this, I need to convert RGB to XYZ values which I know I can do using ConvertColor.

However! I can't figure out an efficient way of being able to convert multiple RGB values stored in data.table into XYZ using ConvertColor. I have a feeling the problem lies in the fact that I can't figure out how to store RGB values as numeric values rather than characters.

My data.table named syn_RGB will be set out as follows:

| ID | Grapheme | RGB_1 | RGB_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S01 | A | (37, 13, 219) | (39, 23, 211) |
| S01 | B | (50, 3, 19) | (40, 23, 11) |
| S02 | A | (43, 57, 89) | (50, 50, 78) |
| S02 | B | (48, 59, 199) | (50, 63, 178) |
| S03 | A | (100, 123, 209) | (89, 112, 200) |
| S03 | B | (89, 120, 199) | (87, 119, 175) |

`RGB_1` is the RGB given for the first time, `RGB_2` the RGB given the second time.

This is what I've tried so far:

```r
syn_XYZ <- synRGB(,. (s_xyz = convertColor(RGB_1, from = "sRGB", to = "XYZ", clip = TRUE)), by =. (ID, Grapheme)]
```

Here I'm trying to convert all the RGB values listed in `RGB_1` into `XYZ` values for each participant and each grapheme and store them in `syn_XYZ`.

I've tried converting the RGB values from characters to numeric using `as.numeric` and `strtoi` but it doesn't work as you can imagine.

I'm still relatively new to programming so if there's a far more efficient way than trying to do it like this, I would be very appreciative since this is the only way I can think of how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `data.table` has anything "efficient" for this, it's just a handling of a string vector. As clunky as it looks, this works:

```r
do.call(rgb, c(asplit(do.call(rbind, lapply(regmatches(syn_RGB$RGB_1, gregexpr("\\d+", syn_RGB$RGB_1)), as.integer)), 2), list(maxColorValue = 255)))
# [1] "#250DDB" "#320313" "#2B3959" "#303BC7" "#647BD1" "#5978C7"
```

Walk through, mostly inside-out:

- `regmatches(., gregexpr("\\d+", .))` extracts things that look like numbers into individual numbers; i.e., `"(37, 13, 219)"` is converted into `c("37", "13", "219")`; this returns a `list` with the same length as `nrow(syn_RGB)`
- `lapply(., as.integer)` converts the list of strings into a list of integer; e.g., `list(c("37", "13", "219"), c("52", "3", "19"), ...)` into `list(c(37, 13, 219), c(52, 3, 19), ...)`.
- We start with (effectively) a list of "R, G, B" values, but to programmatically use that with another function, it would help to have a list with all Rs, all Gs, and all Bs in respective vectors; to do that, `do.call(rbind, .)` converts that list of vectors into a matrix, and then `asplit(., 2)` converts it to a list of columns as we need.
- `do.call(rgb, .)` calls the `rgb` function (once) with each of the three values of the `asplit(., 2)` list as its arguments, adding the argument of `list(maxColorValue=255)` (since `rgb` normally wants its values to be on `[0,1]`).

Comment: thansk r2evans! So that will give me the hex code colours, how do I then convert the hex to XYZ values between 0 and 1?

Comment: Not sure what your intended output is, but perhaps after `do.call`, divide by 255?

Comment: I tried and I'm unsure the RGB relation is preserved correctly. Different angle: I've found the schemr package and its rgb_to_xyz function. I've adapted your code to be able to use it but now I need to define the linear transformation matrix. 
`x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(regmatches(synRGB$RGB_1, gregexpr("\\d+", synRGB$Time1)), as.integer))`
I then put that into a data.table called d1 and then tried
`XYZ1 <- rgb_to_xyz(data.frame(r = d1$red, g = d1$green, b = d1$blue), transformation = "sRGB", linear_func = NULL)`
How do I define the sRGB to XYZ matrix (in the sRGB wiki) for linear_func?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB this is the wikipedia page I was referring to. It's the on listed in the Help for rgb_to_xyz in r.

Comment: *"unsure the RGB relation is preserved"* sounds much more like a fundamental question about colorspace management and not (yet) about how to program it. If you doubt the colorspace-purity of `rgb`, then you are far beyond the color-concerns of my experience, so I think I'm out. However, you might have luck with more targeted searches. On google, for instance, I used `CRAN "sRGB"` ("CRAN" for R's package repository) and some links seem promising.